# index out of bounds with itertuples : IndexError: index 850 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 786

Tags: python

My dataframe

```
userID storeID rating
0   1    662    3.6
1   2    665    3.4
2   3    678    4.0
3   4    500    3.1
4   5    421    2.9


n_users = df.userID.unique().shape[0]
n_stores = df.storeID.unique().shape[0]
```

I have 2 problems. if i want to built my training dataset like that

```
ratings = np.zeros((n_users, n_stores))
for row in df.itertuples():
    ratings[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]
```

I have IndexEroor like this

```
IndexError: index 850 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 786
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you want in expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you're trying to make a 2-dimensional array of floats, each representing a rating, indexed by the user ID in the first axis and the store ID in the second axis.

You're creating an array of shape `(n_users, n_stores)`, where `n_users` and `n_stores` are the number of unique users and stores respectively. When indexing this array,

> ```py
> for row in df.itertuples():
>    ratings[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]
> ```

you're using the user/store ID directly (shifted by 1) as an index. This only works if you know that all user/store IDs range from 1 to the number of unique users/stores, without any gaps in between. For example, given the snippet of dataframe you have shown, there are 5 unique users and 5 unique stores, but even if I make a 5 by 5 array, I won't be able to index the second axis (store ID) directly, since the values of store ID are `[662, 665, 678, 500, 421]`, but it can only be indexed by `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The `IndexError` that you get is happening in axis 1 (i.e. the second axis, the one for the store IDs) with index value 850. That means that your store numbers are not contiguous from 1 to 786 (the number of unique store IDs), but rather they are just "individual" integers with gaps in between, since there is a store with ID 850.

What you're looking for is more like a dictionary: an arbitrary mapping between keys and values, in which the indices (keys) don't have to be contiguous, like for an array. Specifically, I think whatever you're trying to do will be much easier by getting a `ratings` series indexed by a `MultiIndex` of `userID` and `storeID`:

```py
>>> indexed_df = df.set_index(['userID', 'storeID'])
>>> indexed_df
                rating
userID storeID
1      662         3.6
2      665         3.4
3      678         4.0
4      500         3.1
5      421         2.9

>>> ratings = indexed_df['ratings']
>>> ratings
userID  storeID
1       662        3.6
2       665        3.4
3       678        4.0
4       500        3.1
5       421        2.9
Name: rating, dtype: float64
```

Comment: ratings_train, ratings_test = train_test_split(ratings, test_size=0.33, random_state=42) //

ratings_train.shape, ratings_test.shape //

cosine_distances(ratings_train)

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Comment: @JeongHunChoi `train_test_split` expects a 2D array, while `ratings` is a Series (1D). For that, you don't need to do any of this, just pass your original dataframe `df` (or even `indexed_df`) to `train_test_split` and do any processing afterwards.